# How do I select text except for the first letter?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I know that [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) selects the first letter of a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).

How can I select all text except the first letter?

I tried `:not(::first-letter)` but that didn't select anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`:not` [can only be applied to *simple* selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation). Pseudo-elements aren't [simple selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#simple-selector), so you can't invert them.

You could apply the "non-first letter" styles to all of the text and reverse them for the first letter.

For example:

```css
p {
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p::first-letter {
  color: black;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<p>red capitals except the first letter.</p>
```

Comment: You may want to link to the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation) and also indicate why pseudo-elements cannot be arguments to `:not` (it is because pseudo-element is not a simple selector). Just a suggestion :)

Comment: It's worth noting that for properties such as color, `color: currentColor` will *not* work here, because the ::first-letter box, like all pseudo-element boxes, is a descendant of the p box and so its currentColor will be that of the rest of the text - red. That is why the original color has to be hardcoded back in.